# Can OR be replaced with shorter condition in SQL query if we searching by different values of the same field

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need get all records from a table where field must match one of the values.
So query will be:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field="val_1" OR field="val_2" OR field="val_3"`

I am not an expert in SQL so question is:
Can ORs be replaced with something else like: WHERE field OR val_1, val_2, val_3 or similar?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IN` Operator

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field in ('val_1','val_2','val_3')
```